# How to Debug Tridion Templates and Workflows?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am new to SDL Tridion world and I have been assigned a couple of activities:

Create Page Template (PT), Component Template (CT), and a Sample Workflow. Basically I am experienced in .NET.

I have some startup code to start with, and I would like to know is there any way to debug the PT, CT, Workflow from Visual Studio 2010?

Your suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to debug directly on the CMS server, or will you be debugging remotely?

Answer (score 3):

For compound templates either CT or PT, here is Tridion documentation (login required) with clear instructions on how to debug.
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/idheading-259229208

For Workflow, it depends on what type of implementation you are following (VBScript or Event System (TOM .net) or Core Service ), but in general it is not different as above. You attach to the process and debug.
http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_BC70576958F3420CA4FC87B27CB0FC38

Comment: Workflow service will be running on your CMS Server. You login to your CMS Server and open VS attach to the workflow service. If you have to debug from Remote you can check here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx. I haven't tried remote debugging, I always do it from CMS server as it is easy and quick.