# Back to Author Not working and not giving any error

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

The below back to author code is not working in core service based workflow.

and not giving any error. any suggestions?

```cs
public void BackToAuthor(string workitemid)
{
  var client = new CoreServiceSession();
  var csClient = client.GetClient();
  var readoption = new ReadOptions();

  var workitem = (WorkItemData)csClient.Read(workitemid, readoption);
  var processInstance = (ProcessInstanceData)csClient.Read(
                                             workitem.Process.IdRef, readoption);
  var ieActivities = processInstance.Activities;

  if (ieActivities != null)
  {
    var targetactivity = (ActivityInstanceData)csClient.Read(
                                  processInstance.Activities[0].Id, readoption);
    var finishData = new ActivityFinishData();
    finishData.Message = "Finished automatically";
    finishData.NextAssignee = new LinkToTrusteeData { 
        IdRef = processInstance.Activities[0].Performers[0].IdRef, 
        Title = processInstance.Activities[0].Performers[0].Title };
      csClient.FinishActivity(targetactivity.Id, finishData, readoption);
      logdetails("Finished the activity");
      csClient.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably not the cause of your problem, but I suggest **not** catching the exception and instead letting it escape. Whoever called your code probably will do a better job at logging it then your custom `logdetails` does.

Comment: Frank, you mean, the code is correct? if so, then why the item is not moved back to the author? any clue?

Comment: One of the mistakes in your code is catching an exception that you don't handle. That has nothing to do with the problem you're reporting (otherwise I would have provided an answer and not a comment), but will hurt your users once you put it into production.

Comment: Ok, I have changed the code to assing to performer instead of owner, but am getting error in event log "The workflow activity is finished" and still the item is not moved to the last performer, it sits in the global worklist itself (In the automatic activity "back to author")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have to send the activity back to the performer not to the owner (which is "everyone" for the very first activity). You might have to change the following lines of code...

```
finishData.NextAssignee = new LinkToTrusteeData { 
        IdRef = processInstance.Activities[0].Performer.IdRef, 
        Title = processInstance.Activities[0].Performer.Title };
```

Comment: I have changed the code to assing to performer instead of owner, but am getting error in event log "The workflow activity is finished" and still the item is not moved to the last performer, it sits in the global worklist itself (In the automatic activity "back to author")

Comment: What is error message you're getting ? Could you please post the stack trace or full event log..

Comment: An error occurred while executing the Workflow script.
The Script Engine returned the following information:

SOURCE:

  Line = 6
  Column = 4
  Number = -2146233087
  Source = mscorlib

  Description = The Workflow Activity is finished.
  HelpContext = 0
caused by: mscorlib
and description: The Workflow Activity is finished.

Source:
LogScriptError

Comment: Is the Line 6 VBScript where you're calling the BackToAuthor function?

Comment: Yes Ram, i am calling BackToAuthor function from the vbscript

Comment: Code looks good to me, not sure why it is failing. You can run the debugger to step thru and see where it is failing. targetactivity.Id --> Is this returning a TcmUri or string ? It should be string. You can also check here on how to debug, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366385/how-to-debug-tridion-templates-and-workflows

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the `ActivityInstanceData.ActivityState` (`processInstance.Activities[0]`) property? When it's finished already you will get the exception you mentioned. In that case you need to restart the activity: `ICoreService2011.RestartActivity(activityInstanceId, readBackOptions)`

So, how does your process definition look like? Is BackToAuthor called from an Automatic Activity, after the first Activity in the Process Definition?

Comment: first activity is "create or edit", second is "Review", if reviewer rejects, am calling the Backtoauthor automated activity, otherwise calling publish activity this is also automated activity.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest first that you get the code running under a debugger, and verify that the Ids are what you expect. For example, is the process instance correct, and are the various activities and performers what you expect?